# How to check two flags at the same time in a single condition

Tags: c

I would like to be able to check two flags in a single condition but I can't find the right way to do it.

Here is an example of one of the things I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FLAG_1 0x01
#define FLAG_2 0x02

void check_flags(int flags)
{
    if (flags & FLAG_1)
        printf("Flag 1\n");

    else if (flags & FLAG_2)
        printf("Flag 2\n");

    else if (flags & FLAG_1 | FLAG_2)
        printf("Flag 1 and 2\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    check_flags(FLAG_1 | FLAG_2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your current solution looks like a chained if/else with 3 conditions.  What do you mean by "single condition"?

Comment: @WilliamPursell The three conditions are by way of example, the "single condition" I wanted to talk about is the 3rd, sorry if it was not very clear.

Comment: `flags & (FLAG_1 | FLAG_2)` that checks whether one of both is set, not both together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *two* problems:

The first problem is your use of `if ... else if ...` It will be clearer if we reformat the code somewhat:

```
if (flags & FLAG_1)
{
    printf("Flag 1\n");
}
else
{
    if (flags & FLAG_2)
    {
        printf("Flag 2\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if (flags & FLAG_1 | FLAG_2)
        {
            printf("Flag 1 and 2\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Because `if (flags & FLAG_1)` will be true, the code won't check any other condition. You need to change the order of your checks.

The second is because the bitwise AND operator `&` have higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than bitwise OR `|`. The expression `flags & FLAG_1 | FLAG_2` is really the same as `(flags & FLAG_1) | FLAG_2`, which will always be "true".

Putting it all together, try something like this:

```
if (flags & (FLAG_1 | FLAG_2) == (FLAG_1 | FLAG_2))
    printf("Flag 1 and 2\n");
else if (flags & FLAG_1)
    printf("Flag 1\n");
else if (flags & FLAG_2)
    printf("Flag 2\n");
```

Comment: Third problem: `flags & (FLAG_1 | FLAG_2)` is true if `FLAG1` is set **or** `FLAG2` is set. So your `else if` clauses are unreachable.

Comment: @rici I knew there was something I forgot. :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
(flags & (FLAG_1 | FLAG_2)) == (FLAG_1 | FLAG_2)
```

Moreover, move this check at the beginning because otherwise it will be dominated by `if (flags & FLAG_1)` branch.